# Using a try/catch to deal with deep object drill downs that will often fail

Tags: javascript

I have

```
try{
    var progress = raw_progress[module_id][modulette_id][tab_id][track_id];
    if(progress.started){
        count += 3;
    }
    if(progress.complete){
        count += 3;
    }
    return count + 'of_6';
}catch(e){
    return '0_of_6';
}
```

... and the `raw_progress` object might not have a match on any of the items in the drill down of the object.

I could do:

```
raw_progress[module_id] && 
raw_progress[module_id][modulette_id] && 
...
```

...but that seems just too verbose. Is this the best way to deal with drilling down into a javascript object that might reach a dead end at any time?

Answer (score 3):

Does it matter?

In your example, whether you have 1 or 3 layers deep before you hit the same exception, the end result appears the same.

It seems that you do not actually care what layer the exception is generated at in terms of how your logic works. Which means it doesn't matter.

Now, if your return had some level of "went X levels deep" then you would care. But in your case, all failures return the same thing.

I would probably put a comment explaining your catch, though, since right now you are catching *all* exceptions without attempting to log or explain them.